# `sudo -u` in script still prompts for invoking user password

Tags: shell-script, sudo

I'm logged in as `user1` and I have two scripts, script1 attempts to call script2 using `sudo -u user2`. My problem is that I'm still prompted to enter password for `user1` although I'm specifying `-u` option for `sudo`. Here is my setup:

1. Script1:

   ```
   #! /bin/bash

   echo "Current user in script1:" $USER

   # Call script2
   sudo -u user2 /full/path/to/script2
   ```
2. Script2:

   ```
   #! /bin/bash

   echo "Current user in script2:" $USER

   # Execute command as user2
   some-command-that-works
   ```
3. Equivalent `/etc/sudoers` to the one I have:

   ```
   # /etc/sudoers
   #
   # This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
   #
   # See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
   #

   Defaults        env_reset

   # Host alias specification

   # User alias specification

   # Cmnd alias specification

   # User privilege specification
   user1 ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL


   # Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
   # (Note that later entries override this, so you might need to move
   # it further down)
   %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
   #
   #includedir /etc/sudoers.d

   # Don't ask for user2 password for script2
   user2 ALL= NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/script2

   # FYI: I experimented with the line below for group1 that user1 is a member of
   %group1 ALL= NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/script2
   ```
4. `ls -blah` output

   ```
   drwxrwsr-x 2 user1 group1 4.0K Oct 19 15:22 .
   drwxrwsr-x 7 user1 group1 4.0K Oct 18 18:48 ..
   -rwxrwxr-x 1 user1 group1  180 Oct 20 17:37 script1
   -rwx------ 1 user2 group1  166 Oct 20 16:29 script2
   ```

An example of my shell attempt to run `script1`:

```
user1@host1 /full/path/to/script1 $ script1
Current user in script1: user1
[sudo] password for user1:
```

**Edit:** This is on a server that I connect to with `ssh`. The server is running Debian 6.0.4 `Squeeze`

Comment: In case you hadn't realised, `user1 ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` allows user1 to run any command as any user - including root.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sudo -u <user>` gives a user permission to run a command as the given user.

It is not the same as `su - <user>`, which switches you to the given user.  `su - <user>` requires you to enter the password for the given user in order to open a session as that user.

`sudo -u <user>` requires the current users password unless the `NOPASSWD:` flag is given in the sudoers file.

To achieve your desired functionality add this to your sudoers file

```
%group1 ALL=(user2) NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/script2
```

This will allow group1 to run script2 as user2 without entering a password.

Comment: Infact, `user1` is a part of group that needs the same functionality. As you see in the last line my `etc\sudoers`, I was trying to give `NOPASSWD` to `group1` for `script1` but to no avail.

Comment: run `sudo -l /full/path/to/script2`. I suspect that the `user1 ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` is taking precedence over the lower group directive.  The ouput from `sudo -l` should show `NOPASSWD:` if that is in effect.

Comment: Here is what I got for `sudo -l /full/path/to/script2`:    `/full/path/to/script2`, and nothing else. It just listed the path to the script.

Comment: I don't understand why this line: `%group1 ALL= NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/script2` is not taking precedence over the rest of the sudoers file.

Comment: Also, I tried `user1 user2= :NOPASSWORD /full/path/to/script2` in `/etc/sudoers` but `visudo` could not parse it.

Comment: Sorry, that should be    user1  ALL=(user2) NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/script2       I will edit my answer

Comment: Dave please edit your answer for `group1` if possible.

Comment: It finally worked. But I want to leave a comment here for others if they run into the same problem. My last problem in `/etc/sudoers` was that `user1` had an entry as follows `user1 ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`. Instead of explicitly specifying user access in `/etc/sudoers` I add `user1` to `sudo` group and removed the aforementioned line.